# adding request param to every request using spring resttemplate

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to add common request parameters to every request using `RestTemplate`. 
For example if my `url` is `http://something.com/countries/US` then I want to add common request param `?id=12345`. This common request parameter needs to be added on all request. I don't want to add this on each call and want something common.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394414/add-query-parameter-to-every-rest-request-using-spring-resttemplate) post has answer that was marked correct, but I am not sure how you can add request parameters on `org.springframework.http.HttpRequest`

Any other way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To add request parameters to the `HttpRequest` , you can first use `UriComponentsBuilder` to build an new `URI` based on the existing `URI` but adding the query parameters that you want to add.

Then use `HttpRequestWrapper` to wrap the existing request but only override its `URI` with the updated `URI`.

Code wise it looks like:

```java
public class AddQueryParameterInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
            throws IOException {

        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(request)
                .queryParam("id", 12345)
                .build().toUri();
        
        HttpRequest modifiedRequest = new HttpRequestWrapper(request) {
        
            @Override
            public URI getURI() {
                return uri;
            }
        };
        return execution.execute(modifiedRequest, body);
    }

}
```

And add the interceptor to the `RestTemplate`:

```java
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
interceptors.add(new AddQueryParamterInterceptor());

restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
```

Comment: UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest is deprecated now since Spring 6.1. 
use instead ForwardedHeaderUtils.adaptFromForwardedHeaders

Answer (score 1):

for Spring 6.1 / Spring Boot 3.2.x

```java
    // inject apikey in URI query parameter
    ClientHttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = (request, body, execution) -> {

        HttpRequest modifiedRequest = new HttpRequestWrapper(request) {

            @Override
            public URI getURI() {
                return ForwardedHeaderUtils.adaptFromForwardedHeaders(request.getURI(), request.getHeaders())
                        .queryParam("apikey", omdbApikey)
                        .build(true)
                        .toUri();
            }
        };

        return execution.execute(modifiedRequest, body);
    };
```

The interceptor can be used in a RestTemplate/WebClient/RestClient

example:

```java
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.Builder
                .requestInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things are required to add common request parameters to every request using RestTemplate.

1. Create a prototype bean RestTemplate

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {
    @Bean
    @Scope(
            value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE,
            proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate localRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = localRestTemplate.getInterceptors();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
            interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        interceptors.add(new AddQueryParamterInterceptor());
        localRestTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return localRestTemplate;
    }
}
```

2. Use the Interceptor code as suggested by @ken-chan to add the request parameters. A new instance of Resttemaple will be created and for each and every request.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by adding interceptor to rest template

Comment: that I know. but how was my question.